# How to parse full xml divs with child content but without child tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have xml files with large  sections that contain tagged text.
I need to parse out the content stripped of the child tags or replaced to create html links.

This is content of sample.xml:

```
<BODY><ENTRY id="AB">Blabla</ENTRY>
<ENTRY id="XY"> This is the city of <LOC ref="at0001">Vienna</LOC>, which until <YEAR>1918</YEAR> blablabla</ENTRY></BODY>
```

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parsedxml=ET.parse('sample.xml')        
xmlroot = parsedxml.getroot()
section=xmlroot.find(".//*[@id='XY']").text
```

Return: "This is the city of "

What I need is either

"This is the city of Vienna, which until 1918 blablabla, lots of similar tags.".

or, ideally:

"This is the city of < a href="mypage/at0001" >Vienna< /a >, which until 1918 blablabla, lots of similar tags."

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example? See:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are `ET` and `filename`?

Comment: edited code accordingly. will do minimal reproducible example too

Comment: It should be fairly easy to do if you can use lxml instead of elementtree.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the text "This is the city of Vienna, which until 1918 blablabla" in the example above would be to use `xmltodict` and `json`. See below:

```
import xmltodict
import json
xml = """
<BODY><ENTRY id="AB">Blabla</ENTRY>
<ENTRY id="XY"> This is the city of <LOC ref="at0001">Vienna</LOC>, which until <YEAR>1918</YEAR> blablabla</ENTRY></BODY>
"""
data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml)
json_string = json.dumps(data_dict)
xml_json = json.loads(json_string)
text_i_want = xml_json['BODY']['ENTRY'][1]['#text']
print("text_i_want:", text_i_want)
```